# How to make a List<Entity> on a variable with a cast

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit

so I am trying to make a Minecraft plugin that listens to the configuration file for input of which mobs to not target players. Here is what I have so far

```
public class ZombieListener implements Listener {
    private final List<String> entities;
    public ZombieListener(List<String> entities){
        this.entities = entities;
    }
    @EventHandler
    public void onEntityTargetEvent(EntityTargetLivingEntityEvent event) {
        if (event.getTarget() event.getTarget() instanceof Player ) {
            final Player targeted = (Player) event.getTarget();
            if (targeted.hasPermission("dont.target.me") && entities.contains(targeted)){
                event.setCancelled(true);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I realise that I can't check for an entity from an object and therefore I need to make `targeted` a List. How should I do this?

Comment: You probably don't need the check `event.getTarget() instanceof Entity`

Comment: edited (forgot that I added that in whoops)

Comment: I think you should use Enteryset It would be give better result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The other answer is way more complex than it needs to be. Try to do this instead:

```
public class ZombieListener implements Listener {

    private final List<String> entities;

    public ZombieListener(List<String> entities){
        this.entities = entities;
    }

    @EventHandler
    public void onEntityTargetEvent(EntityTargetLivingEntityEvent event) {
        if (event.getTarget() instanceof Player && entities.contains(event.getEntityType().getName())) {
            final Player targeted = (Player) event.getTarget();
            if (targeted.hasPermission("dont.target.me") && entities.contains(targeted)) {
                event.setCancelled(true);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

All I did was add a small bit of code in the first if-statement:

```
entities.contains(event.getEntityType().getName())
```

This makes it so the application checks if the entity is one of the affected types, and carries on with the listener accordingly.

Hope this helps!

Comment: *`event.getEntityType().getName()`* You should not have to stringify an enum. Enums work just fine as dictionary keys.

Comment: @Draco18s I wanted to tamper with his original code as little as possible. In his original code segment, he used strings so I left it as such.

Answer (score -1):

## Use the entity class instead.

For example I created a mod that caused animals to age over time, making them die (they also would breed on their own). In order to allow the config to determine how quickly animals aged, I used [the animal class](https://github.com/Draco18s/HarderStuff/blob/master/src/main/java/com/draco18s/wildlife/entity/ai/EntityAIAging.java#L33):

```
private Class species;
private Entity entity;

public EntityAIAging(Random random, EntityAnimal ent, Class spec, EntityAgeTracker ageTracker) {
    species = spec;
    entity = ent;
    //...
}

public void updateTask() {
    // Both of these function the same:
    // Unaging animals do not age, do not die, and do not procreate
    if(HardLibAPI.animalManager.isUnaging(species)) {
        return;
    }
    if(HardLibAPI.animalManager.isUnaging(entity.getClass())) {
        return;
    }
    //...
}
```

So what you'd want to do is call `entity.getClass()` and check if it exists within a `List<Class> entities`. If you want to see how I parsed a config file to locate classes, you can see that code [here](https://github.com/Draco18s/HarderStuff/blob/master/src/main/java/com/draco18s/wildlife/util/AnimalUtil.java#L71). Its complicated and has some additional logic to handle minor misspellings.

Comment: There's no need to actually start working with the NMS code and using external libraries. All he was missing was a single if statement to check if the source entity was the proper type.

Comment: @MichaelZiluck What do you mean by "external libraries"? `HardLibAPI` is mine and only used as an example of how I used the data and not meant to be used wholesale. I don't know what NMS is either (nor does Google).

Comment: His question is about Bukkit, not about Forge or other mod systems. NMS refers to using and manipulating the `net.minecraft.server` packages and classes within a plugin. Bukkit plugins aren't supposed to touch NMS unless you absolutely have to, as it is not as stable as using the overlaying API. Here is a good explanation about why NMS is bad when working with Bukkit: https://riptutorial.com/bukkit/topic/9576/nms

Comment: @MichaelZiluck I did not know this question was Bukkit related when I answered it (nor was it tagged as such until 2 days later).